# Why global styles in Next.js project at Codesandbox don't work although place import in _app.js?

Tags: next.js

Here my project
https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-booth-if8f5?file=/pages/index.js

When I create _app.js and place import after that the styles don't work as expected. Wondering why...

Comment: You need to export the App too. Add this in `_app` --- `export { default } from 'next/app';`